# What is this "Freeze" language?

Tags: germanic-languages

I remember having a side discussion with a professor in college and he told be about a nearly extinct language; the closest thing I can remember to its name is "Freeze". Apparently its spoken on some island around the English channel, and I believe it's supposed to be "pure" old english, not contaminated by other languages. However, I haven't been able to find this language by googling. Can you help me find it? Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

This is the Frisian language—actually, there are three Frisian language: West Frisian spoken in the Dutch province of Friesland with capital Leeuwarden, East Frisian spoken by very few people in three villages around Friesoythe in Northern Niedersachsen, Germany, and North Frisian spoken on the North Frisian Islands and Helgoland, Schleswig-Holstein, Germany.

It is a myth that Frisian is "pure Old English", it was a separate, but closely related language even at the time when Old English was actually spoken. It has evolved since that time, and the different Frisian languages were heavily influenced by their big neighbours (Dutch for West Frisian, Low German for East Frisian and North Frisian).